# How to make pdf generation faster with clj-pdf?

Tags: clojure

I am using clj-pdf library to generate a page with 40000 pages with same two images on each page.
Its taking me around 1 minute 30 seconds to generate the pdf which is quite too much considering we used to do it faster with python.
What all can I do make it faster ?

Here is the stacktrace.

```
user=> (defn 
  #_=>  gen-pdf
  #_=>  []
  #_=>  (println (new java.util.Date))
  #_=>  (pdf [{}  (for [i (range 80000)] (do  [:paragraph [:image "sample_logos/batman.jpeg"] [:image "sample_logos/superman.jpeg"] ] ) )] "super.pdf")
  #_=>  (println (new java.util.Date)))
#'user/gen-pdf
user=> (gen-pdf)
#inst "2013-12-26T07:03:05.695-00:00"
#inst "2013-12-26T07:04:23.175-00:00"
nil
user=>
```

Comment: Add more details: your "fast" python program, it's timings, version of libraries you use, size of output files etc. Test images can be added too.

Comment: we used to use reportlab. I am not sure how much time it would take but from my experience. its a little too much here.
Just wanted to know, what can I do to improve the above sample code.. i am sure lot can be done there also.

Comment: So you don't know the numbers in Python but yet you say that in Clojure it is slow?

Comment: Nope. actually, we used to process much slightly larger datasets in Python that used to take 50k packing slips in 3 minutes... each packing slip used to have around 4-5 logo images.

I am expecting JVM performance to be slightly better than what I am getting.

If I load buffered images in memory will it make writing to disk faster ? I am not comparing clojure to python, I am just trying to verify if my code can do pdf generation faster.

Ourt prior experience was with Python so I was expecting JVM to be around 2-3 x faster.

I dont know..how much better cna I go..thats why..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Author of clj-pdf was so kind to add [references](https://github.com/yogthos/clj-pdf#reference) to library. Here is updated code using "1.11.9" version of clj-pdf:

```
(defn gen-pdf []
  (time
   (pdf [{:references {:batman [:image "sample_logos/batman.jpeg"]
                       :superman [:image "sample_logos/superman.jpeg"]}}
         (for [i (range 80000)]
           [:paragraph
            [:reference :batman]
            [:reference :superman]])]
        "super.pdf")))
```

which finish in **12 seconds** on my machine.

---

I ran your example using [clj-pdf "1.11.7"], it took about **68 seconds** and generated **5.4Gb** file.

Then I created a python sample:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from datetime import datetime

batman = "sample_logos/batman.jpeg"
superman = "sample_logos/superman.jpeg"
n = 80000

def hello(c):
    for i in range(0, n):
        c.drawImage(batman, 0,0)
        c.showPage()
    for i in range(0, n):
        c.drawImage(superman, 0,0)
        c.showPage()

t1 = datetime.now()
c = canvas.Canvas("super_py.pdf")
hello(c)
c.save()
t2 = datetime.now()

print (t2 - t1)
```

It is roughly equivalent, using python 2.7.5+ and reportlab 2.7 it took **53 seconds** and generated **108Mb** file.

Reportlab reuse the same image so I changed clj-pdf to allow to pass iText Image in `:image` tag - see https://github.com/yogthos/clj-pdf/blob/master/src/clj_pdf/core.clj#L461

I have added another condition to pass Image instances *as-is*:

```
(let [img (cond
            (instance? Image img-data)
            img-data
            (instance? java.awt.Image img-data)
            (Image/getInstance (.createImage ...
```

and changed code to

```
(defn gen-pdf []
  (let [batman (Image/getInstance "sample_logos/batman.jpeg")
        superman (Image/getInstance "sample_logos/superman.jpeg")]
    (time
     (pdf [{}
           (for [i (range 80000)]
             [:paragraph
              ;; [:image "sample_logos/batman.jpeg"]
              ;; [:image "sample_logos/superman.jpeg"]
              [:image batman]
              [:image superman]])]
          "super.pdf"))))
```

This optimization allowed me to generate pdf in **17 seconds** and **70 Mb**

Comment: How do I get the latest clj-pdf with ur changes ?

Comment: I didn't publish, you can clone repo and publish on clojars.
keep watching the ticket https://github.com/yogthos/clj-pdf/issues/22

Comment: are you the author/contributor ?

Comment: no, I'm not author/contributor. :) I just answer SO questions!

Comment: I just checked. nice work by you guys. I am really liking the clojure community :)

Comment: I used this new tag. the time came down from 36 seconds to 6 seconds for the two jpegs i used!

Comment: Author here, after a bit of tinkering I decided to simply cache any images/charts by default. With the latest version you should see the same improvement without having to use the :reference for these elements.

Comment: @Yogthos: checked without reference now. caching works fine. but shall I rely on it always? if i know I am gonna repeat a page multiple times with different data, shall I just make a reference of such resources and still use I found using reference to be 100msec faster on average?
what I want to do is to generate packing slips/reports with different data cming from db.
I will use template for it, and use references for logos in it.
its gonna be like 40-100k slips most of the time.

Comment: and yeah.. does iText use threading internally ?
is there a way I can generate separate pages in separate threads and combine them into one pdf to make the process even faster ?
kind of map-reduce :P?

Comment: Any image, chart, or svg tags will now be cached based on their object hash. The explicit reference will still be slightly faster, but there shouldn't be a huge difference. If you're already creating the refs then I would keep that. There's currently no threading in the library, but that's something I could look into for the next version. :)

Comment: I think the tricky part with threading would be how to partition the input. When individual tags are simple then the overhead of spawning the threads might overshadow any performance gains. This would be difficult to infer automatically.

Comment: @edbond: template is a macro, any idea how do i use reference with it? data in each template will chnage but can we cache rest of it ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar references should works fine in templates, provide a code example here or on github issues